# My daughter room barely gets airflow. After looking in vent with camera the vent comes to a small point. Why would this be made like this?

Tags: vent, air

[image][image]Little airflow through vent. Can only get camera to a point and looks like a small hole. Is this normal for a vent, why would the vent be made this way.

Comment: please add the picture

Comment: It probably has a shutter that can be opened or closed. [edit] to add the picture.  If you need to change browsers or devices, [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/login) first.

Comment: Picture added @jsotola

Comment: It would be normal camera perspective that the air vent looks like this

Comment: take a picture of one of your "good" vents

Comment: That vent tube looks good to me, do not get fooled by the optics, your problem is somewhere else

Comment: From that picture I can see that either the pipe goes 4m and stays at 150mm diameter or it goes 0.4m and reduces to 15mm diameter.

Comment: It is possible that there is a damper in that duct at some point.  For some reason it is/has been closed/reduced and is why for the reduced air flow.  Most dampers are placed where they are accessible(if you are lucky).  The simple handle ones are just a piece of 1 inch wide by 6 inch long thin metal on the outside of the duct.

Comment: @knowtail picture taken with an endoscope and I can’t get it to go past this point